# CSS counter span element behaviour

Tags: css-counter

I am trying to get the hang of CSS counters but seems like I am not able to make sense of it.

Here is a minimal example I hava:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    counter-reset: chapter;
    counter-reset: section;
    counter-reset: theorem;
}

.outline-1 {
    counter-increment: chapter ;
}

span[class^="section-number"] {
    counter-increment: section ;
}
.theorem:before {
    counter-increment: theorem;
    content: "Theorem " counter(chapter) "." counter(section) "." counter(theorem) ": ";
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="outline-container-sec-1-2" class="outline-1">
<h3 id="sec-1-2"><span class="section-number-1">1.2</span> Basic</h3>
<div class="theorem"> Very important theorem! </div></div>

<div id="outline-container-sec-1-2" class="outline-1">
<h3 id="sec-1-2"><span class="section-number-2">1.2</span> Some  Combinatorics</h3>
<div class="theorem"> Very important theorem! </div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The result I get is:

1.1 Basic

Theorem 1.0.1: Very important theorem!

1.2 Some Combinatorics

Theorem 2.0.2:Very important theorem!

Why the second counter stays at 0? Why can I count the span elements?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    counter-reset: chapter;
    counter-reset: section;
    counter-reset: theorem;
}

.outline-1 {
    counter-reset: section;
    counter-increment: chapter ;
    
}

span[class^="section-number"] {
    counter-increment: section ;
}
.theorem:before {
    counter-increment: theorem;
    content: "Theorem " counter(chapter) "." counter(section) "." counter(theorem) ": ";
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="outline-container-sec-1-2" class="outline-1">
<h3 id="sec-1-2"><span class="section-number-1">1.2</span> Basic</h3>
<div class="theorem"> Very important theorem! </div></div>

<div id="outline-container-sec-1-2" class="outline-1">
<h3 id="sec-1-2"><span class="section-number-2">1.2</span> Some  Combinatorics</h3>
<div class="theorem"> Very important theorem! </div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But why it was 0 before?

Comment: This thing works online but not on my local machine, interesting.

Comment: It works when I include the CSS manually in the head of my HTML, between style tags. But if I put it in a CSS file and link it, it does not work.

Comment: @meguli Are you using this ?`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">`

Comment: Maybe it's a browser problem